# Pass data between queues - Stomp

Tags: python, activemq-classic, message-queue, stomp

Is it possible to share data between queues in stomp? We have a new project and my task is pass data from one queue to another. Consider a system with ActiveMQ and Stomp. In this system I have find a message that return by queue1 and pass to queue2. This doesn't make much sense to me. Any advice about this issue would be appreciated.

Use Case:

I have an application like this:

- queue1 : make query from ldap and find user
- queue2 : make query from exchange server with given user

I want to use "user" founded from queue1 for query in queue2

Comment: It is unclear from your question what exactly you are trying to do, please try and elaborate in order to get some help.

Comment: @TimBish Thank you. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can move messages between queues within the same broker, or across brokers.

**Same broker use case:**

Application sends message to queue1 on brokerA. Using ActiveMQ's Composite Destination support, you could configure brokerA to also deliver the message to queue2 on brokerA.

**Different broker use case:**

Application sends message to queue1 on brokerA, the messages are then passed queue2 on brokerB using a bridge, or an ActiveMQ network connector.

Additionally, code could read a message from queue1 on brokerA, perform some processing and then publish the message to queue2 on brokerB.

*As Tim mentioned in his comment, additional detail identifying which use case applies to you is needed in order to recommend the best solution.*